# Google tag manager preview and debug mode showing variables undefined

Tags: google-tag-manager, facebook-marketing-api

I am using facebook pixel with Google Tag manager. I have page view datalayer. I have made one custom tag for facebook like following

```
<script>
fbq('trackCustom', 'MyCustomEvent', { categoryname: '{{DL_ecomm_category}}'});
</script>
```

But now when I view in Google Tag manager preview and debug mode then it is showing variables undefined. I am attaching screen shot of variable and datalayer screen.

[image]

[image]

I am not getting what could be the reason? Is it problem in firing trigger or there should be custom data layer?

Comment: You don't seem to have populated those variables. Where should the variables data be coming from?

Comment: Do I need to add them from website using datalayer.push or is there any method with google tag manager?

Comment: You can either use a datalayer push (https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/data-layer/) or you can define a variable that locates the element you're interested in, such as a DOM variable or a Custom Javascript variable (https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/variable-guide-google-tag-manager/)

Comment: Try removing single qoute from '{{DL_ecomm_category}}'